# nestjs multiple db connection

Tags: node.js, nestjs, decorator, typeorm

I want multiple db connection in nestjs, But it only connect the db when it is requested not at the time of start. For this I have created a param decorator and using this decorator in one of my service file. Getting the below error.

[image]

My decorator code below

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { getConnection, createConnection, ConnectionOptions } from "typeorm";
import { User } from '../../entity/user';

export const Database = createParamDecorator(
    async (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
        console.log('decorator param->', data);

        let connection;
        let options;
        if (data == "otherdb") {
            options = {
                name: 'jwt',
                type: "mysql",
                host: "localhost",
                port: 3306,
                username: "root",
                password: "",
                database: 'jwt-user',
                entities: [User],
                synchronize: false
            };
        } else {
            options = {
                name: 'jwt',
                type: "mysql",
                host: "localhost",
                port: 3306,
                username: "root",
                password: "",
                database: 'jwt-auth',
                entities: [User],
                synchronize: false
            };
        }

        const connectionOption: ConnectionOptions = options;

        try {
            connection = getConnection(connectionOption.name);
        } catch (error) {
            connection = await createConnection(connectionOption);
        }

        console.log('cccc');
        console.log(typeof connection);


        return connection;
    },
);
```

Service code below

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository, Connection } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from '../entity/user';
import { Database } from '../modules/database/database.decorator';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    constructor(@Database() connection: Connection) {

    }
}
```

Comment: The [official documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#multiple-databases) already explained on how to manage multiple db connections and how to inject data source object to services